# Opening Different activities based on Notification action clicks

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I am trying to make  Notification Reply like whatsapp.

here is my code

```
public void sendNotification(String msg, Intent i, ContactModel contact)
    {
        i.putExtra("message", msg);
        i.putExtra("contact", new Gson().toJson(contact));
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        String replyLabel = "Reply";
        RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder("KEY_REPLY")
                .setLabel(replyLabel)
                .build();

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean("reply", true);
        NotificationCompat.Action replyAction = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
                R.drawable.ic_phone, replyLabel, contentIntent)
                .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                .addExtras(bundle)
                .setAllowGeneratedReplies(true)
                .build();

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                        .setContentTitle(contact.getName())
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText("Content Hidden"))
                        .setContentText(msg)
                        .addAction(replyAction)
                ;

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.cancel(Constants.PUSH_ID);
        mNotificationManager.notify(Constants.PUSH_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Now my notification shows "Message" and a "Reply" Button.

The problem i am facing is, i can't differentiate wether user chose Reply button or tried to open the notification.

My main intent is

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
```

What i want is,
When a user click on "Reply" Button it opens

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
```

When a user click on notification itself it opens

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

Even if thats not possible , how can i figure out which action was performed.

[image]

Comment: Where are defined "Message" and "Reply" Buttons ?

Comment: There is no message button, only reply and content message

Comment: See if my post could help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
setContentIntent(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class))
```

Additional info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContentIntent(android.app.PendingIntent))

Comment: Still notification activity is opening when i click on Icon and message content

Answer (score 0):

You should create a pending intent for each case , one for reply button and another for your message notification.

`addAction()` define action button for your notificaion, and `setContentIntent(pendingIntent)` do the same for your core message.

```
.... your code

    Intent messageIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent messagePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 200, messageIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                            .setContentTitle(contact.getName())
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                    .bigText("Content Hidden"))
                            .setContentText(msg)
                            .setContentIntent(messagePendingIntent)   // some change here
                            .addAction(replyAction)
```

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: i tried that but it still opens notification activity as if MainActivity doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your statement is: you are expecting two different intents for two different actions so, I'm not confirm that it will solve your problem, but this is what I tried.

```
public void createNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificatioTest.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,(int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent mPIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,(int)System.currentTimeMillis(),mIntent,0);
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Your Title")
            .setContentText("Your text content")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Reply", mPIntent).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
}
```

The change is I have used two different `PendingIntent` as `setContentIntent(pIntent)` and `addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Reply",mPIentent)`.

Output:
https://youtu.be/vVKVMboHEOA